# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::user()

Tags: php, laravel, session

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::user() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\vms_ut\resources\views\layouts\navbar.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\vms_ut\resources\views\layouts\navbar.blade.php)

> View

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{url('/home')}}">Home</a></li> &nbsp&nbsp
                    @if (Session::user()->level == 'Admin')
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                            Master <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="">Data</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Warehouse</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                     @else  (Session::user()->level == 'Penyedia')
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                            Master <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="">Data</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
```

view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEK9u.png)

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean Auth instead of Session?

Change this line:

```
@if (Session::user()->level == 'Admin')
```

To this line

```
@if (Auth::user()->level == 'Admin')
```

Comment: don't use auth.

Comment: @FantioMrgno What do you mean dont use `auth`? The error says that it cant find a method called `user()`. So obviously, as it stands, you can't use `user()` with Session. If you want to get the authenticated user stored in session, `Auth::user()` is the default laravel way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session facade as such:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session ;`